# About priority of nginx location / {} and location = {}

Tags: nginx

When I study about the nginx location configuration, I have some questions.Here is my example.

the files structure is like this:
test1/index.html
test2/index.html

and the nginx.conf location part is like below:

```
    location = / {
            root test1;
            index index.html;
    #       deny all;
    }
    location  / {
        root test2;
        index  index.html;
    }
```

the question is , when i issue curl -v http://host/, I get the page of test2/index.html , but when I get rid of the # in the location = / {} part,
the result will be 403 forbidden. can anyone explain why ? when both the location = same_uri {A} and location same_uri {B} are in the configuration file,which configuration will match[A or B]? Thank you very much.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you request the URI `/`, `nginx` will process two requests.

The first request (for the URI `/`) is processed by the `location = /` block, because that has highest precedence. The function of that block is to change the request to `/index.html` and restart the search for a matching `location` block.

The second request (for the URI `/index.html`) is processed by the `location /` block, because that matches any URI that does not match a more specific `location`.

So the final response comes from the second `location` block, but both blocks are involved in evaluating access.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for `location` syntax and [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) on the `index` directive.